# Access CQ5 project bundles on same instance

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, aem

I have two project bundles my local CQ/AEM server. Project A contains some java Util class methods which can be utilized in project B as well.
While developing, how do I import my project A classes in project B to access the methods so that I do not have to duplicate the methods again?

I tried adding dependency in my Project B bundle pom.xml as below. Is this correct?

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project-a</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-project-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get missing artifact error for this. 
"Missing artifact com.project-a:cq-project-a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT"

Please suggest how the import can be done.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say if it's correct, when we do not see groupId/artifactId/version from the POM file of module you are trying to depend on. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Can you confirm that you run command "mvn install" successfully on project a ?

Comment: @TienNguyen, Yes I do run "mvn install" successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to build project a using mvn install. The dependency will be searched in your local maven repo.

Comment: Thanks @Christian , I have installed project A and it is visible in the OSGi console, if that is what you were referring to.

Comment: No. I was referring to just the build process. Of course you will need to install project A at runtime too. The next thing is how you create the bundle. I guess you use the maven-bundle-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This solution may fix you issue: update your `pom.xml` on project a, modify groupId, artifactId, version, packaging tags and make sure they look likes:

```
<groupId>com.project-a</groupId>
<artifactId>cq-project-a</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

Then run `mvn clean install` on project a, run `mvn clean install` one more time one project b. I applied this to my last project, I hope it works for you.